# google guice does not work in android project

Tags: java, android, guice

I need DI library to my android library project - library, so I do not need things like injecting Activities/Fragments views etc. So such Dagger2 does not fit my needs. There are no nice ways to inject objects to my POJO classes.

I consider Google Guice but I get exceptions in my android project. Otherwise in pure Java project the same code is running well.

I have such code (at this line app crashes):

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyInjector());
```

MyInjector:

```
public class MyInjector extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(FooInterface.class).to(FooImplementation.class);
    }
}
```

Gradle:

```
implementation group: 'com.google.inject', name: 'guice', version: '4.0'
```

And have so long stacktrace:

```
com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2199)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3934)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3938)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4821)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4827)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:136)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:547)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:884)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:805)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:282)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:214)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalFactory(InjectorImpl.java:890)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.notify(FactoryProxy.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.runCreationListeners(ProcessedBindingData.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:134)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at com.example.diresearch.services.ServiceManager.<init>(ServiceManager.java:26)
    at com.example.diresearch.Plugin.init(Plugin.java:19)
    at com.example.diresearch.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:32)
    at com.example.diresearch.ExampleInstrumentedTest.buildPluginInstance(ExampleInstrumentedTest.java:21)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:101)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
    at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:384)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1939)
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper.create(MethodWrapper.java:34)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DuplicatesPredicate.evaluate(DuplicatesPredicate.java:25)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CollectionUtils.filter(CollectionUtils.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:64)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClass(BytecodeGen.java:204)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.create(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:159)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:90)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:29)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:37)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:33)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load(FailableCache.java:37)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3524)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2317)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2280)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2195)
    ... 52 more
    Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:237)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:144)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:116)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper.<clinit>(MethodWrapper.java:22)
    ... 72 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:384)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:219)
    ... 77 more
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: can't load this type of class file
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:594)
    ... 80 more
```

Comment: Why do you think Dagger 2 doesn't fit your needs?  Dagger2 has no problem injecting other classes, and doesn't require you to inject activities etc.

Comment: I can't resolve how to inject fields in my POJO class without boilerplate code. For every field I have to write something like this:


    foo1 = DaggerFooComponent.create().getFoo1();

Comment: No you don't.  If you think you do, you don't understand how Dagger works at all and need to read some tutorials.

Comment: Okay, you have right. I got it now. I missed inject() method in Component class.